# Used to be able to

Tags: meaning

"Us demons used to be able to take over bodies, but Lucifer took away that ability years ago."

Does this mean from the time Lucifer took away the demon's ability, to the beginning of their time, they had the ability to take over bodies? Or does it leave the possibility that they didn't HAVE this ability to take over bodies since the beginning, and maybe they acquired it over evolution or something?

How would you interpret it?

Comment: The given sentence only addresses the fact that demons lost the ability, it says nothing about how they acquired the ability in the first place so there isn't enough information to be able to answer.

Comment: *"Does this mean from the time Lucifer took away the demon's ability, to the beginning of their time"* - You've worded this in a confusing way. When we say something happened "from X to Y" normally X is when it started and Y is when it finished. (Incidentally, if you're talking about the TV show, Lucifer didn't take the ability away, he simply forbade its use.)

Comment: I used to be able to run 100m in 14 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence of events in time. First, there was a period when demons were able to take over bodies; second, at the end of that period, at some time in the past, Lucifer removed that ability from the demons; third, a period of time passed; and last, the demons now give us their account of these events.

These are the events described by your prose. Any considerations of when the demons received the ability or how it evolved are mere speculation and are not dealt with by the prose.